# what is the difference among sleep() , usleep() & [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:]?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa

Can any body explain me what is the difference among sleep() , usleep() &  [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:] ?

What is the best condition to use these methods ?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

sleep(3) is a posix standard library method that attempts to suspend the calling thread for the amount of time specified in seconds. usleep(3) does the same, except it takes a time in microseconds instead. Both are actually implemented with the nanosleep(2) system call.

The last method does the same thing except that it is part of the Foundation framework rather than being a C library call. It takes an NSTimeInterval that represents the amount of time to be slept as a double indicating seconds and fractions of a second.

For all intents and purposes, they all do functionally the same thing, i.e., attempt to suspend the calling thread for some specified amount of time.

Answer (score 22):

> What is the best condition to use
>   these methods ?

## Never

Or, really, pretty much almost assuredly never ever outside of the most unique of circumstances.

What are you trying to do?

Comment: But Bill, I find that sleeping for a few nanoseconds here and there clears up all of my inexplicable EXC_BAD_ACCESS crashes!

Comment: Heh.  I cringe time I see code that uses `usleep()` for "thread synchronization" purposes.  My cringe muscles are sadly sore.

Comment: I know exactly what you mean. In this case, I was hoping to exercise the smile muscles rather than the cringe :)

Comment: I wish more people would see this answer because I've seen `sleep()` used once but wasn't sure if it was because they didn't know what they were doing. Now I'm sure they had no clue.

Comment: @lucius: There are some valid uses for sleep, just not what most people use it for these days, which was the gist of my joke.

Comment: Honestly, I'm having a difficult time thinking of a single valid use for sleep() anymore. Far, far, better off to use a system timer and leave the thread free to do other stuff.

Comment: I use usleep with UIView animations. Some subviews react differently than others with UIView animations. The sleep is so short, it barely affects the thread, which at those moments has nothing going on anyways, by design. What you should never do is *never* use a potentially good tool, even if those situations are rare.

Comment: Thus preventing that thread from doing other useful work, causing it to block (using kernel resources), and incurring fragility that will be the source of potential maintenance happy-funtimes as the # of cores and/or concurrency model of the underlying system changes over time.  Core Animation (and UIView animation therein) has scheduling features for a reason.

Comment: i am working on a project that has a million lines of code.  the single sleep() in the entire codebase is in debug code that is there to help us test catching when the main thread is not responding.

Comment: @john.k.doe That's a bug waiting to happen.  Say you have a sleep of every 500ms;  unless you have convoluted math to determine when the last main thread event was processed, you'll end up with a variable failure window.  Better to have a heartbeat type scenario that is managed by a secondary thread and service by the main, secondary thread blocking on signals from the main, not on unrelated wall time.

Comment: i think you misunderstand.  the only sleep is a sleep of 90s.  not 90ms.  and it is only exercised in test code.  my point is that i agreed with you that using sleep() is bad.

Answer (score 3):

On most OSs, sleep(0) and its variants can be used to improve efficiency in a polling situation to give other threads a chance to work until the thread scheduler decides to wake up the polling thread. It beats a full-on while loop. I haven't found much use for a non-zero timeout though, and apple in particular has done a pretty good job of building an event driven architecture that should eliminate the need for polling in most situations anyway.

Answer (score -1):

-**Example** usage of sleep is in the following state:

In **network simulation scenario**, we usually  have events that are executed event by event,using a scheduler. The scheduler executes  events in orderly fashion.
When an event is finished executing, and the scheduler moves to the next event, the scheduler compares the next event execution time with the machine clock. If the next event is scheduled for a future time, the simulator sleeps until that realtime is reached and then executes the next event.

-From linux **Man** pages:

The **usleep()** function suspends execution of the calling thread for (at least) usec microseconds. The sleep may be lengthened slightly by any system activity or by the time spent processing the call or by the granularity of system timers.
while **sleep** is delaying the execution of a task(could be a thread or anything) for sometime .Refer to [1](http://linux.die.net/man/3/usleep) and [2](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sleep) for more details about the functions.