# How to reduce the initial time to show loader?

Tags: ios7, xcode5, nstimer, gif, loader

I am implementing loader in button action , but when i click on button it takes 3 to 5 sec to start loading. i am using two controller to implement loader- UIImage+animatedGIF.h to use gif image and MBProgressHUD.h to implement progress time. i don't know how to reduce the initial time that takes to start loader.
I am using this code to implement loader-

```
NSURL *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"loadingg" withExtension:@"gif"];

    self.loader.image = [UIImage animatedImageWithAnimatedGIFData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url]];


    float progress = 0.0f;

    while (progress < 1.0f) {



        progress += 0.01f;

       // HUD.progress = progress;

        usleep(50000);


    }

    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:progress target:self selector:@selector(abcd) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I must assume that `usleep(50000)` is **not** on the main thread.

If it is, there is your **5 secs** delay. Sleeping the main thread does just that: wait. The right approach is an asynchronous load.

Read @bbum recommendation for when it's appropriate to invoke usleep: [what is the difference among sleep() , usleep() & [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3155586/what-is-the-difference-among-sleep-usleep-nsthread-sleepfortimeinterval)

Answer (score 0):

The reason is because it won't display your image until you return from your delegate, and since you block the delegate using the while loop for 5 seconds you experience the behavior you described